# AVR assembler instruction encoding

Tags: assembly, binary, avr, machine-code, instructions

Is the assembly instruction : dec r21

in 16-bit binary..

0000000000010100

and also,

Is there a conversion table for register values to binary?

Comment: `dec r21` will be encoded as `1001010101011010`

Answer (score 2):

```
DEC r12
```

will be translated to `1001 0101 0101 1010`.

To find more and detailed information about the 8-bit AVR instruction set google for "AVR instruction set",
or visit https://www.microchip.com, search for and navigate to the used MCU -> documents -> reference manual -> AVR instruction set manual.
At the time of writing this you can find the manual at http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf

Comment: @thebear8 Broken link has been fixed.

Comment: six years after answering! that's impressive.